# Can I remove the drywall in the area below the door to my attached garage?

Tags: drywall, doors, door-frame

The door frame in the garage is kind of in need of replacement:

[image]

Can I simply remove this whole drywall board and replace it with another one?

[image]

I think those two screws (where the green arrows are) are holding that drywall board in place. Do you think it's a good idea to simply unscrew them, remove the board, and put another one in its place?

Comment: That really shouldn't be just drywall there.  I'm not certain why it was built that way in the first place, but a hardwood threshold would be much better.

Answer (score 2):

If that's an exterior service door, you can do as you like with the drywall. Cut it out at a convenient location and replace it with BC plywood or other suitable material, or simply overlay a board. I've never seen horizontal drywall in that position before, and consider it a bad decision by the builder.

---

*This original answer was given with little context in the question. I mistakenly assumed that this was an entry door connecting to the residence.*

The drywall is probably there as a required fireblock. You should overlay plywood or other suitable material and leave the gypsum in place. Feel free to replace the drywall first if it's in bad condition, though technically the joints must be taped with at least a rough coat.

Comment: The "joints must be taped" between the drywall in the green and the other drywall? Also "taped with a coat" of what?

Comment: And finally, one last comment: that door leads to the outside. You think that there would be a fireblock there?

Comment: @JeniaIvanov "taped with a coat" meaning apply drywall joint compound (aka "mud"), lay drywall tape on the wet mud, allow to dry. Apply another coat of joint compound on top of the mud/tape you laid previously. That would be a "rough coat" because there is no sanding or smoothing done, and would not be necessary for the purposes of fire blocking. In this case, it is blocking air movement between sheets of fire-rated drywall, so flames, smoke, ash, embers, etc. cannot squeeze through.

Comment: @JeniaIvanov fire blocking is mandated by building code, and I am not as familiar with the [IBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Building_Code) as some people. I do know the code requires fire-rated walls between certain units, such as the wall separating two living spaces in a duplex or apartment. It may also require garage walls to be fire-rated, or the wall between the house and an attached garage. Exterior walls may also need some measure of fire rating. What if the neighbor's house catches fire, or you spill gasoline in the driveway and it ignites? Fire rating buys you time.